# Is a file hosted on a webserver discoverable/accessable if there is no link to that file in any page?

Tags: security, web

Say I have folderX on the Public_html folder of my web-server.

A) If I rename the folderX to something very long and random, is it technically possible for someone to access the files in that folder? (other than brute forcing the folder name, which should be slim chances).

B) since there is no link to the files in the renamed folder, or the folder itself, the web crawlers and search engines won't be able to index its content, right?

I understand that this is not a normal way to secure content, and it is recommend to move non-public data to the web-server root ( above the public_html) folder, or password protect them with .htaccess or so. But here I am asking what are chances, and if it is technically possible, and how?

Edit.
I thought about putting the name of folder in the robots.txt file to also make sure it is excluded from the web crawlering bots. But it seems counterproductive!!  The robots.txt file is not obligatory for robots to follow, and by revealing the name of the folder that file a malicious bot can intentionally go there and crawl it. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are relying on [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) - "is it technically possible": of course it is. Is it a problem, well, that's up to you to evaluate. Use a robots file to prevent pages being indexed _not_ obscurity.

Comment: Can you elaborate HOW it is possible, of course except for the brute force method for some one who knows there is a folder there.

Comment: App exploit of any kind, users sharing urls, or if its http simply by sniffing traffic, for example.

Comment: Thanks AD7six for your answer. Now I get it, but now lets say that folder in question has no user, so there is no user sharing the urls, and no one is even accessing those file so packet sniffing will fail. What about App exploit? Can you think of some scenarios in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

- If the connection is over plain HTTP, then any network sniffers could
  determine the URL that is being accessed. The solution to this it to implement certificates and TLS so that the URL is HTTPS, protecting the path and query string portions.
- Even if the connection is HTTPS, many corporate networks decrypt the connection on an outbound proxy because the certificate the proxy server uses is trusted by the client. This may reveal your URL path to network administrators if your URLs are accessed from corporate locations.
- If there are any outbound links or external resources on your "hidden" pages, the `referer` header will leak the URL of your hidden pages to them.
- Tools such as [Nikto](https://cirt.net/Nikto2) or [Dirbuster](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_DirBuster_Project) can find common hidden URLs.

Don't use robots.txt for the reasons you describe. However, [meta tags](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=en) can be used to prevent the indexing of HTML pages.

Comment: Thanks SilverLightFox for the answer.  But what about if no one is accessing those URLs? Then the packet sniffer will fail right? Hence the only real threat is from the brute force methods such as DirBuster.

Comment: Why would you have a url that was never accessed?

Comment: For instance, I have all files a folder of my working website, I make a copy of it, rename the folder to a bizarre name. I want to keep it as a backup and in case the current version of the website goes down, all files of the previous version are there, I can rename that back up folder back to original name and it is immediately accessible. Anyway, here I am curios to know the technicality. If it is possible that this folder is discovered. So far I assume it is possible only with a bruteforce method to guess folder name.

Comment: To answer your question, yes it would either be a brute force method or if there were any directory browsing vulnerabilities in your site or the web server then it may be discoverable. Note that this is not the best location for a backup - why not keep the backup out of web root entirely and you can just move it in there to restore. Additionally, if the backup is the same as your live, does it matter if it is discovered? The main risk may be your secure configuration isn't active on your backup I guess, potentially exposing files that would otherwise be protected.